# How do I fix the overlapping dates?

Tags: date, matplotlib, charts

I want to solve the problem of overlapping dates under the chart. I think it's because there are too many dates displayed. Please let me know?

```
df['Close'] = df['Close'].astype(float)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,7))
plt.plot(df['Date'].values, df['Close'].values, label = 'Bitcoin Stock Price', color = 'red')
plt.xticks(np.arange(100,df.shape[0],200))
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Close ($)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: current plot]

Comment: Consider using concise date formatter.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_concise_formatter.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the `Date` column [**`to_datetime()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) before plotting; then matplotlib will handle the date formatting automatically:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
plt.plot(...)
```